# Openning Links then searching each one of urls then closing each window and adding the urls to an array

Tags: javascript, html, url, dom

I just started getting into javascript and decided to create a script that will take a list of urls and open each url. Once it opens each url, it will search the page for a certain Href and then add it to a global var array. So far I have functions that creates the list of urls that I want to search, but my functions that searches each window doesn't seem to work. When I debugged it to print out the current document url in the Onload function it only prints out only 1 url.

How can I do the process mentioned above without using jquery?
Thank you for your help!

Here is my code.

```
 var yearLinksArray =[];
 var deletePages=[];

 function deleter(){
  for (var i = 0; i< document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;i++){
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href.indexOf("remove")!= -1){
      console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href);
    }

  }

}

function yearLinks(){
  var links = [];
  var deletePages =[];

  var yearLink = "month_2015_2"

   for (var i = 0; i< document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;i++){
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href.indexOf("year_")!= -1){
      links.push(document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href);
      deletePages.push(document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href);

    }

  }

  return links;


}

function addPages(){
  console.log(document.URL);
  for(var year =2015;year!= 2008;year--){
    for (var month =12;month!=0;month--){
      var yearLink = "month_"+year+"_"+month;



      for (var i = 0; i< window.document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;i++){
        if (window.document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href.indexOf(yearLink)!= -1){

          //console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href);
          deletePages.push(window.document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].href);
        }

  }


    }
  }   


}

function searcher(link){

  window.open(link);
  window.onLoad= addPages();

}



yearLinksArray = yearLinks();
for(var i=0;i <yearLinksArray.length;i++){
  searcher(yearLinksArray[i]);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is wrong:

```
function searcher(link){
  window.open(link);
  window.onLoad= addPages();
}
```

It's adding the `onload` handler to the current window, not the window you just opened. It's also calling the `addPages` function immediately, and assigning the result to `window.onload`; you should be setting the `onload` property to the function itself.

```
function searcher(link) {
    var win = window.open(link);
    win.onload = addPages;
}
```

Note that none of this will work if the pages you're loading are in a different domain from your script. Javascript can't access contents of windows in a different domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then is it possible to create html document using a URL so I can do this without opening new windows?

Comment: You can load the HTML into a DIV using AJAX. Or you can just put it into detached DOM elements. But in all these cases, you can't do it across domains unless you use a proxy on your own server. See the Simple PHP Proxy.